# Can I use a project using java 8 in my Android project?

Tags: android, java-8

I maintain an open source library and I received a mail several days ago from a user who wants to use the project on Android. The project uses java 8 features such as `Stream`s and the `Iterable` interface.

I want this library to be usable on Android and I was wondering what would be the best (and simplest) way to make it happen? The project is on Maven Central but I can create a new version of it which works with Android I just wish to learn the steps to do so. Can I simply compile the jar to work with Android if I just change the public API not to use java 8 features?

Comment: Android doesn't do Java 8, but you can add its features with [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).

Comment: Can I just compile the java 8 code to work with a java 7 jvm? Never had to do this before but Maven has this feature (compile target if I remember right).

Comment: You could, but then you would need to remove all the Java 8 features. I assumed you didn't want to do that

Comment: RetroLambda is not going to work since I use `Iterable`s and `Stream`s which are not on its feature list.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Most projects I've seen either work with [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) for the streams.

Comment: A middle ground in terms of simplicity could be to use the streamsupport Java 6 backport of the Java 8 stream API in conjunction with retrolambda. At least, the required code changes would be mostly mechanic and the result could be run both on Android and Java 6 - 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **[Android N preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/first-preview-of-android-n-developer.html)** release Android support **limited** features of **Java 8** see [Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html). `Stream` is not supported yet and only lambda expressions came with backward compatibility

**Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs**

> Android does not currently support all Java 8 language features.
>   However, the following features are now available when developing apps
>   targeting the Android N Preview:

[Default and static interface methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

[Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

[Repeatable annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html)

There are some additional Java 8 features which Android support, you can see complete detail from [Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features)

Answer (score 0):

No, Java 8 will be supported only on Android N or newer. Some of the best features of JAVA 8 are available thought libraries like https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda